# Sencha Touch - Viewport Problem

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, extjs, viewport

i am using the ToolbarDemo and the ListDemo from Drew Neil (@nelstrom)!
Everything works perfect!
But there is one problem with the VIEWPORT - i think!

here is my code:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132823-Viewport-Problem

I hope anyone can help me!
Thanks!

### ---------------------------

EDIT:
thank you mistagrooves for your quick answer!
but now i get this error (Line 33):

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem' [undefined] is not a function.
```

my code:

```
ToolbarDemo.views.detailPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
        id: 'detailpanel',
        tpl: ['<div class="live">',
                        '<div style="float:right;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">{titel}</div>',
                        '<div style="text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">',
                        '<video width="280" height="280" x-webkit-airplay="allow" poster="playlive.png" controls="controls" id="video_player" style="" tabindex="0"><source src="{video}"></source></video>',
                        '</div>'],
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    text: 'zur&uuml;ck',
                    ui: 'back',
                    handler: function() {
                        ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem('disclosurelist', {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    });

ToolbarDemo.views.Beitrage = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {
title: "Beitr&auml;ge",
iconCls: "btnbeitraege",
id: 'disclosurelist',
        store: storeXML,
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><img src="{bild}" width="48" height="26" border="0"/> {titel}</div>',
        grouped: true,
        onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
        var details = Ext.getCmp('detailpanel');
        details.update(record.data);
        //this is ok because Viewport is an object
        ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem('detailpanel');
 } 
});

ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport = new Ext.Panel ({
        fullscreen: true,
        cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
        items: [new ToolbarDemo.views.Beitrage(), new ToolbarDemo.views.detailPanel()]
    });

storeXML.load();
Ext.reg('beitrage', ToolbarDemo.views.Beitrage);
```

i hope anyone can help!
thank you!

Comment: You should include the code that you are trying to debug on stackoverflow as the questions should be self contained.

Comment: Mike, Have you resolve this? I'm trying to correct the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't created anything via 'new'. Essentially you are playing with the classes instead of the objects. ToolbarDemo.views.detailPanel is a Class and not an Panel Object therefore you have to create it before you are able to use it.

You've done it (or copied it) as part of the initialization of the main Viewport:

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport = new Ext.Panel ({
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'card',
        cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
        items: [new ToolbarDemo.views.Beitrage(), new ToolbarDemo.views.detailPanel()]
    });
```

Inside your disclosure function you could do something like:

```
    onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
            var details = Ext.getCmp('detailpanel');
            details.update(record.data);
            //this is ok because Viewport is an object
            ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem('detailpanel');
        }
```

Comment: thank you mistagrooves for your quick answer!
but now i get this error (Line 33):

    TypeError: Result of expression 'ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem' [undefined] is not a function.

Comment: you will need to add a layout of 'card' to the viewport so that you can use setActiveItem on the Viewport (edited answer).  The only other thing that I can recommend at this point is to debug the program in Chrome/Safari so that you can inspect ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport and see what the object references are set to and see if you can trace the error.

Comment: thank you @mistagrooves! i have add the layout of 'card' - but i get the same error! - i have tried debugging the code in safari - but it's very difficult for me - to understand the references...

Comment: can i send you a link to my project (by email)?

Comment: @Mike no, it doesn't get any easier from here.  I would revisit the examples and examine where you went wrong.